# MVC Identity - Use UserManager.ConfirmEmailAsync to check token expired.,

Tags: authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, token, asp.net-identity, email-verification

I am using MVC 5 with OWIN identity authentication.

I have not touched the default auth code. (VS 2013).

Sometimes I get **"error: Invalid token**" when **UserManager.ConfirmEmailAsync()** is called.

I want to know if it's the case were a user clicked the confirm link in his inbox too late.

How can I get a more detailed exception telling me if the token has expired ? (or check it myself somehow)

Comment: Any chance you found a solution for this?

Comment: Duplicate of this (answered): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42971556/identity-framework-test-if-confirm-email-token-is-expired

Answer (score 0):

The verification of the tokens is baked into the providers and is opaque generally, for the default provider it can fail typically in one of two ways: its expired (1 day default expiry), or the security stamp for the user changed (via password change, removing logins, etc)